# Keras Lambda layer runs twice even though called only once

Tags: tensorflow, lambda, keras

Why the following code runs twice gram layer?

```
import numpy as np
from keras.applications import vgg19
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Model

def gram_layer(y):
    print('Using Gram Layer')
    # assert K.ndim(y) == 4
    print(y.shape, 'y.shape')
    # a = y.get_shape()[1].value
    # b = y.get_shape()[2].value
    # c = y.get_shape()[3].value
    # print(a, b, c)
    # x = K.squeeze(y, axis=0)

    # features = K.batch_flatten(K.permute_dimensions(x, (2, 0, 1)))
    # features_nomean = features - K.mean(features, axis=0, keepdims=True)
    # gram = K.dot(features_nomean, K.transpose(features_nomean)) / (a * b * c)
    print('exiting Gram')
    # return x
    return y


In = K.placeholder((1, 256, 256, 3))
model = vgg19.VGG19(input_tensor = In, weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

for layer in model.layers:
    if layer.name == 'block1_conv1':
        print(layer.name)
        print(layer.output.shape)
        outputs = (Lambda(gram_layer))(layer.output)
```

Debug info:

```
block1_conv1
(1, 256, 256, 64)
Using Gram Layer
(1, 256, 256, 64) y.shape
exiting Gram
Using Gram Layer
(?, ?, ?, 64) y.shape
exiting Gram
```

Debug information contains two "Using Gram Layer", it means this layer runs twice, and it fails at the second time, but strangely it's only called once.

Any idea what's wrong?

PS: I realize that the problem lies in the for loop part, if the last line

```
outputs = (Lambda(gram_layer))(layer.output)
```

is replaced as

```
outputs = (Lambda(gram_layer))(In)
```

the debug info goes as

```
block1_conv1
(1, 256, 256, 64)
Using Gram Layer
(1, 256, 256, 3) y.shape
exiting Gram
Using Gram Layer
(?, ?, ?, 3) y.shape
exiting Gram
```

If the last 5 lines are replaced as

```
outputs = (Lambda(gram_layer))(In)
```

then the debug info goes as

```
Using Gram Layer
(1, 256, 256, 3) y.shape
exiting Gram
Using Gram Layer
(1, 256, 256, 3) y.shape
exiting Gram
```

It still runs twice, but the shape inference is correct. Is this a bug? or should I report it at GitHub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why your function is called twice, but it's not uncommon to see that. It's called during compilation first.

The problem there seems to te reshaping with "None" values. That's not supported.

You can reshape with "-1" instead of None, but you can have only one "-1" in a reshape.

**Suggestion 1:**

All your reshape code can be replaced with: `x = K.squeeze(y,axis=0)`

**Warning:**

But this is highly unusual in keras. The `axis=0` dimension is the batch size. This code will only run fine with `batch_size = 1`. (Either your code and my suggestion).

**Suggestion 2:**

If you're going to use `batch_flatten`, why the reshape then?
Any reshape you do before `batch_flatten()` will be pointless, unless you really mean to flatten only the last two dimensions and have a `(256,768)` tensor.

**Suggestion 3:**

If you want the actual values of `a`, `b`, `c` for **calculations**, you need to get their tensor values instead of their config values:

```
shp = K.shape(y)
a = shp[1] #maybe you need shp[1:2], depending on whether you get an error in the division line    
b = shp[2]
c = shp[3]
```

**Suggestion 4:**

It's quite strange to use a placeholder. That's not the keras way of doing it.

You should simply create the model and tell it the shape you want:

```
model = vgg19.VGG19(input_shape = (256,256,64), weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
```

If you do want to enforce a batch size of 1, then you can create an input tensor:

```
inputTensor = Input(batch_shape=(1,256,256,64)   
output = model(inputTensor)
model = Model(inputTensor, output)
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, now I delete most of lines and gram_layer function simply return its input y, but the problem still exists. My code can not continue with a "None" value.

Comment: Sure. I've ready edit the original post, some lines are comment out, and debug info is slightly different.

Comment: I edit my question again. I figure it out that the "None" value is somehow related to the last 5 lines of my code, but I still don't understand why. Do you think I should report it at GitHub?

Comment: You commented all lines of your code, I can't know what you're running. But it's quite strange to use a placeholder. That's not the keras way of doing it. You should simply create a model and pass the shape you want. (Suggestion 4 in the answer).

Comment: I finally solved this after struggling for two days... Thanks for your reply. You are right, the placeholder caused this problem, it should be replaced by a K.variable or simply a shape.